# exponential fit singularity in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit a bi-exponential function on this dataset but I can't seem to get it to converge.  I've tried using `nls2` grid search for the best starting point, I've also tried using `nlsLM` but neither method works.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

> function: y = a1*exp(-n1*t) + a2*exp(-n2*t) + c

here is the code:

```
y <- c(1324,1115,1140,934,1013,982,1048,1143,754,906,895,900,765,808,680,731,728,794,706,531,629,629,519,514,516,454,465,630,415,347,257,363,275,379,329,263,301,315,283,354,230,257,196,268,262,236,220,239,255,213,275,273,294,169,257,178,207,169,169,297,
227,189,214,168,263,227,185,220,169,229,174,231,178,141,195,223,258,206,181,200,150,200,169,194,230,162,174,194,225,216,196,213,150,235,231,224,244,161,219,222,210,
186,188,197,177,251,248,223,273,145,257,236,214,194,211,213,175,168,223,192,318,
263,234,163,202,239,189,216,206,185,185,191,340,145,188,305,112,252,213,245,240,196,196,179,235,241,177,196,191,181,240,164,202,201,306,214,212,185,192,178,203,203,239,141,203,190,216,174,219,153,177,223,207,186,213,173,210,191,258,277)
t <- seq(1,length(y),1)

mydata <- data.frame(t=t,y=y)
library(nls2)
fo <- y~a1*exp(-n1*t)+a2*exp(-n2*t)+c
grd <- expand.grid(a1=seq(-12030,1100,by=3000),
              a2=seq(-22110,1900,by=2000),
              n1=seq(0.01,.95,by=0.4),
              n2=seq(0.02,.9,by=0.25),
              c=seq(100,400,by=50))

fit <- nls2(fo, data=allout, start=grd, algorithm='brute-force', control=list(maxiter=100))
fit2 <- nls(fo, data=allout, start=as.list(coef(fit)), control=list(minFactor=1e-12, maxiter=200),trace=F)
```

> error: maximum iteration exceeded

However, if I use `nlsLM` then I get singularity gradient matrix at initial parameter estimate.

Comment: Did you run your code? t and y have different lengths.

Comment: you also use the `nls(y~SSbiexp(x,A1,lrc1,A2,lrc2)` which is a self-starting fit.

Comment: sorry about that... t and y are now the same length.